# ADB shell get connected speakers battery level

Tags: android, shell, adb

I've been playing around with the adb shell and I've been wondering about a scenario.

Imagine you have an adb server connected to an android device. The android device itself is connected via bluetooth to a speaker. Can you query the speakers battery level? I've tried a few queries but so far I could only return battery level of the android device and manufacturer information of the speaker.

```bash
adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.device.action.MANAGE_BATTERY -d "btspec://dev_addr=<RE_ADR>"
adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager | grep -A 3 "<Speaker Name>" | grep "Battery Level"
adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager | grep -i "<speaker-name>"
```

However if I check the android device's bluetooth settings and look for the speaker, I have a text stating the battery level e.g. `Remaining battery level 70%`.
It seems like the speaker does send information, but how can I access this?